# Preencher modal do Bootstrap com valor de uma div

Tags: jquery, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma tabela na qual o valor carregador dentro dela através do PHP, precisa estar no value de alguns inputs que estão em uma janela modal do boostrap. Já tentei várias soluções, porém, naõ funciona.
Quando eu clico na linha da tabela, ela carrega o modal, mas o campo fica vazio. Pretendo fazer assim, utilizando a linha da tabela para carregar o modal, e não um button para carregar o modal.
segue o código:
Tabela HTML

```
<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_editar_veiculo">
   <td id="teste"><?php echo $linha['PLACA'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $linha['NOME'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $linha['ANO'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $linha['CPF'] ?></td>
</tr>
```

Janela modal:

```
<!-- Modal editar cadastro veículo -->
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="modal_editar_veiculo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Alterar dados do veículo</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="modal_novo_item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" id="nome" name="nome">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ano" id="ano" name="ano"> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Placa" id="placa"  name="placa">
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <select name="proprietario">
                        <?php listar_editar( $link ); ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
               </div>
              </form>

                </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar janela</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Alterar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

A janela é aberta, porém não funciona. Em outro projeto já tinah feito isso, com outro código jQuery, porém, o que carregava o modal era um button. Tentei adequar ao meu código, mas nada.
Grato desde já.

Jquery que deveria estar funcionando:

```
 <!--Open modal for editions -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
    var valorDaDiv = $("#teste").text();    
    $("#placa").val(valorDaDiv);
 };
</script>
```

Comment: Qual o html da tabela?

Comment: E versão do bootstrap?

Comment: O primeiro item é a linha tabela, na qual eu quero clicar, e abrir o modal. Quer ver a tabela inteira?

Comment: Bootstrap 4.0.0

Comment: seria bom porque aqui funcionou normal.

Comment: Deve ter outra coisa dando conflito

Comment: Com esses códigos que enviei? não creio

Comment: Rapaz, você pode editar a pergunta colocando as bibliotecas usadas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode pegar o texto da primeira `td` e jogar no campo da modal com o evento `.click`:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   $("[data-toggle='modal']").click(function(){
      var valorDaDiv = $("td:first", this).text();
      $("#placa").val(valorDaDiv);
   });
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
   $("[data-toggle='modal']").click(function(){
      var valorDaDiv = $("td:first", this).text();
      $("#placa").val(valorDaDiv);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table>
<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_editar_veiculo">
   <td>123</td>
    <td>nome</td>
    <td>ano</td>
    <td>cpf</td>
</tr>
<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_editar_veiculo">
   <td>456</td>
    <td>nome</td>
    <td>ano</td>
    <td>cpf</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- Modal editar cadastro veículo -->
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="modal_editar_veiculo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Alterar dados do veículo</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="modal_novo_item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" id="nome" name="nome">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ano" id="ano" name="ano"> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Placa" id="placa"  name="placa">
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <select name="proprietario">
                        <?php listar_editar( $link ); ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
               </div>
              </form>

                </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar janela</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Alterar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Se quiser colocar cada texto nos devidos campos da modal, use `.eq()`, onde `.eq(0)` é o texto da primeira `td` e assim sucessivamente:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
   $("tr[data-toggle='modal']").click(function(){
      var placa = $("td:eq(0)", this).text();
      var ano = $("td:eq(1)", this).text();
      var nome = $("td:eq(2)", this).text();
      $("#placa").val(placa);
      $("#nome").val(ano);
      $("#ano").val(nome);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table>
<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_editar_veiculo">
   <td>123</td>
    <td>fulano</td>
    <td>1997</td>
    <td>cpf</td>
</tr>
<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_editar_veiculo">
   <td>456</td>
    <td>ciclano</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>cpf</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- Modal editar cadastro veículo -->
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="modal_editar_veiculo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Alterar dados do veículo</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="modal_novo_item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" id="nome" name="nome">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ano" id="ano" name="ano"> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Placa" id="placa"  name="placa">
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <select name="proprietario">
                        <?php listar_editar( $link ); ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
               </div>
              </form>

                </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar janela</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Alterar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Continua não funcionando. Deve ser  por causa da listagem em Php, sobre o que tu falou de repetir o id. No caso o 'data-toggle="modal"' é repetido sempre, como se fosse o identificador

Comment: Veja que tirei os ids.... não precisa deles.

Comment: esse popper.min.js não é necessário!

Comment: Não é não... eh que o meu link pro bootstrap puro não tah mais funcionando.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Dá uma olhada nisso... acho que vc mata fácil: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/295309/8063

Comment: É vdd, com essa biblioteca da sua resposta tem que colocar ele. Fiz teste e comprovei

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo È, quando tem algumas funcionalidades tem que ter o popper

Comment: Mas na minha resposta não usei ele e funciona bem, outras bibliotecas

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Eu tenho um link pro CDN mas a porcarria não ta´funcionando, aí boto essas aí mermo

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("tr[data-toggle='modal']").click(function(){
    
    //valores das células da linha clicada
    var a = $(this).text();

    //split de a porque cada valor está separado por um \n (nova linha)
    var n = a.split('\n');

    //atribuindo os valores aos devidos inputs
    $("#placa").val(n[1]);
    $("#nome").val(n[2]);
    $("#ano").val(n[3]);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<table width="300">

<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_editar_veiculo">
    <td>ASD 123</td>
    <td>Igor</td>
    <td>2018</td>
    <td>CPF</td>
</tr>

<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_editar_veiculo">
   <td>QWE 456</td>
    <td>dvd</td>
    <td>19eAntigamente</td>
    <td>CPF 2</td>
</tr>

<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_editar_veiculo">
   <td>AAA 001</td>
    <td>Leo</td>
    <td>2021</td>
    <td>CPF 3</td>
</tr>

</table>
    
    
 <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="modal_editar_veiculo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
             <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Alterar dados do veículo</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="modal_novo_item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" id="nome" name="nome">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ano" id="ano" name="ano"> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Placa" id="placa"  name="placa">
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <select name="proprietario">
                        <?php listar_editar( $link ); ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
               </div>
              </form>

                </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar janela</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Alterar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Ainda não funciona aqui

Comment: to usando a versão 3.1 do jquery pra todas as outras funções, e a 4.0.0 pro bootstrap

Comment: @Igor Então, veja com versão 3.1 do jquery e boostrap 4.0.0 em http://kithomepage.com/sos/preencher-modal.html Inclusive a resposta foi editada para essas bibliotecas.

Comment: @Igor alguma coisa vc está fazendo errado ou alguma outra biblioteca está conflitando.

Comment: Funciona certim

Comment: Bom, com os arquivos no diretório funciona. Mas eu preciso usar apenas as CDN deles. Poderia por favor me enviar os links das CDN do BS e do Jquery usados aí? quero me certificar que peguei a mesma que tu vai usar e funcionar

Comment: são as que estão na resposta