# verificar se apenas um campo for igual ao digitado no input

Tags: php

Como eu verifico se um campo da minha tabela for igual ao digitado ? estou tentando fazer uma URL amigavel, só que estou tendo problemas quanto a verificação da URL se ela ja existe no banco de dados, oque estou fazendo de errado ? só está imprimindo a mensagem de `Esta URL não está disponível` mesmo eu digitando uma que não esteja no banco

**INDEX.PHP**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title>Bem Vindo</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <input type="text" id="url"/>
 <div id="resultados"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#url").on('keyup', function(){

        var url = $("#url").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'buscaURL.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {urlParaMontar: url},
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#resultados").html("Carregando...");
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#resultados").html(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                $("#resultados").html("Ouve um erro ao enviar sua URL");
            }
        });//ajax
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**buscaURL.php**

```
<?php 
$url = $_POST['urlParaMontar'];

$a = array('A', 'À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'B', 'C', 'Ç', 'D', 'E', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'J', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'X', 'Z', 'W', 'Y', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'Ā', 'ā', 'Ă', 'ă', 'Ą', 'ą', 'Ć', 'ć', 'Ĉ', 'ĉ', 'Ċ', 'ċ', 'Č', 'č', 'Ď', 'ď', 'Đ', 'đ', 'Ē', 'ē', 'Ĕ', 'ĕ', 'Ė', 'ė', 'Ę', 'ę', 'Ě', 'ě', 'Ĝ', 'ĝ', 'Ğ', 'ğ', 'Ġ', 'ġ', 'Ģ', 'ģ', 'Ĥ', 'ĥ', 'Ħ', 'ħ', 'Ĩ', 'ĩ', 'Ī', 'ī', 'Ĭ', 'ĭ', 'Į', 'į', 'İ', 'ı', 'Ĳ', 'ĳ', 'Ĵ', 'ĵ', 'Ķ', 'ķ', 'Ĺ', 'ĺ', 'Ļ', 'ļ', 'Ľ', 'ľ', 'Ŀ', 'ŀ', 'Ł', 'ł', 'Ń', 'ń', 'Ņ', 'ņ', 'Ň', 'ň', 'ŉ', 'Ō', 'ō', 'Ŏ', 'ŏ', 'Ő', 'ő', 'Œ', 'œ', 'Ŕ', 'ŕ', 'Ŗ', 'ŗ', 'Ř', 'ř', 'Ś', 'ś', 'Ŝ', 'ŝ', 'Ş', 'ş', 'Š', 'š', 'Ţ', 'ţ', 'Ť', 'ť', 'Ŧ', 'ŧ', 'Ũ', 'ũ', 'Ū', 'ū', 'Ŭ', 'ŭ', 'Ů', 'ů', 'Ű', 'ű', 'Ų', 'ų', 'Ŵ', 'ŵ', 'Ŷ', 'ŷ', 'Ÿ', 'Ź', 'ź', 'Ż', 'ż', 'Ž', 'ž', 'ſ', 'ƒ', 'Ơ', 'ơ', 'Ư', 'ư', 'Ǎ', 'ǎ', 'Ǐ', 'ǐ', 'Ǒ', 'ǒ', 'Ǔ', 'ǔ', 'Ǖ', 'ǖ', 'Ǘ', 'ǘ', 'Ǚ', 'ǚ', 'Ǜ', 'ǜ', 'Ǻ', 'ǻ', 'Ǽ', 'ǽ', 'Ǿ', 'ǿ','&',' ','!','/','#','$','*','@','('); 

$b = array('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'j', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'z', 'w', 'y', 'd', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 's', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'y', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'ij', 'ij', 'j', 'j', 'k', 'k', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'oe', 'oe', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 's', 's', 's', 's', 's', 's', 's', 's', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'w', 'w', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 's', 'f', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'a', 'a', 'i', 'i', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'ae', 'o', 'o','e','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-');

$urlNova = str_replace($a,$b,$url);

$conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=noticias',"root","");

    $sql = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM `artigos`");
    $sql->execute();
    $fetchAll = $sql->fetchAll();

    if(isset($urlNova) && $urlNova === $urlNova){
        echo "Esta URL não está disponível";
    }else{
        echo $urlNova;
    }

?>
```

e na tabela `artigos` só tem o campo `url` que tem o valor `url-teste-do-site`

Comment: Falta um WHERE aí não?

Comment: `where url = '$url'` ? eu nao to passando nenhum parametro na URL, eu tenho um input que digita uma url qualquer, se nao estiver ela no banco mostra ela normalmente, se estiver mostra essa mensagem de erro, porem esta mostrando o erro mesmo nao tendo a url no banco

Comment: Pois eh, acho estranho não verificar se existe no banco com WHERE.

Comment: a unica soluçao foi deixar o campo `unico` no banco, mais não queria fazer isso, queria uma verificação bonitinha, se souber uma solução posta ai amigo, obrigado

Comment: deixe uns exemplos para nós, senão fica difícil, que o que você quer é verificar se algum parâmetro da url é igual a um campo na tabela seria isso?

Comment: o código que você postou não faz sentido conforme o @dvd já comentou, do jeito que você postou, ele sempre vai cair na condição de imprimir que não está disponível

Comment: Uma verificação bonitinha seria ver se no banco existe a tal URL com WHERE. Pelo que estou vendo, você não está fazendo nada a não ser fazer uma simples consulta ao banco com `"SELECT * FROM `artigos`")`

Comment: o que há na tua tabela artigos? e o que há na tua url?

Comment: Uma pergunta bonitinha seria postar também o HTML para evitar que nós tenhamos trabalho extra em digitar o mesmo.

Comment: Sem falar que esse if não faz o menor sentido.

Comment: editei a pergunta, ve se entendem melhor agora, oque eu quero é so verificar se o campo digitado no input ja esta cadastrado no banco de dados, eu pensei que para usar o `where` eu teria que passar algum parametro na `url`

Comment: Blz, vou estudar esse caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aproveitando seu código fiz as adaptações necessárias para pleno funcionamento.

```
$url = $_POST['urlParaMontar'];
$a = ......
$b = ......
$urlNova = str_replace($a,$b,$url);

$conexao = .....

/*********verifica se existe no banco alguma url igual a digitada*********/

    $sql = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM artigos where url='$urlNova'");
    $sql->execute();

    $linha = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //se existe é colocada nessa variavel
    $urlBanco = $linha['url'];

/**************************** fim verificação ****************************/

    if(isset($url) && $urlBanco === $urlNova){
        echo "Esta URL existe no banco";
    }else{
        echo "url digitada " .$url. " Nao existe no banco "; 
    }
```

> OBS: fazer uma requisição assíncrona e fazer um select cada vez que o usuário digita um caractere não é a melhor maneira. Eu mudaria o evento  `keyup` na linha
>
> `$("#url").on('keyup', function(){` da index.php para
>
> `$("#url").on('blur', function(){`
>
> **ou usaria a versão 1.1 abaixo!!**

**Versão 1.1 :)**

```
function isValidUrl(url){

var myVariable = url;
    if(/^[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/i.test(myVariable)) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }   
}


$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input').keyup(function() {
        $th = $(this);

        if (isValidUrl($th.val())==1){

          $.ajax({
            url: 'buscaURL.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {urlParaMontar: $th.val()},
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#resultados").html("Carregando...");
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#resultados").html(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                $("#resultados").html("Ouve um erro ao enviar sua URL");
            }
         });//ajax 

      }

    });
});
```

> A função `isValidUrl` verifica se a url é válida dentro do padrão estabelecido. Somente se a URL digitada for válida é que executa o método `$.ajax({` que permite enviar e tratar o resultado evitando assim executar vários selects.

**Caso queira validação completa da `url` desde http ..... use**

```
if(/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/i.test(myVariable)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria diferente de você:
Verificaria no banco se aquela url já existe. Se a consulta apresentar alguma linha significa que ela tem resultado, portanto a url já existe. Senão, está disponível para ser utilizada.
O código ficaria assim:

```
//Consulta buscando a url na base. Como não sei o nome do campo da sua tabela, só substituir url pelo campo correto
$sql = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM `artigos` WHERE **url** LIKE '$urlNova'");
$sql->execute();
//Verificar se a consulta retornou algo.
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if($num_rows > 0) {
 echo "Esta URL não está disponível";
} else {
 echo $urlNova;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Revise sua consulta ao banco e a condição que valida o resultado da consulta, segue um exemplo de como eu faria pra resolver essa situação.
lembrando que há várias formas de resolver esse problema, nesse caso aconselho que no `WHERE` da sua consulta ao banco você não utilize o `LIKE`, pois é uma busca por um valor exato.

```
$urlNova = str_replace($a,$b,$url);

$conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=noticias',"root","");

$sql = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM `artigos` WHERE url = '$urlNova'");
$sql->execute();

$resultado = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($sql->rowCount() == 0){//verifica se a urlNova está cadastrada no banco
    echo "Esta URL não está disponível";
}else{
    echo $urlNova;
    //echo $resultado['url'];
}
```

Comment: eu pensava que para usar o `where` eu teria que passar algum parametro na `URL`

Comment: Você pode montar a sua "urlNova", e comparar com a url que está armazenada no banco. O mais pratico seria vc criar a url válida, com base no id do artigo ou então com base no titulo do artigo.